# VBA - create diagram with different column range

Tags: vba, excel

In my Workbook i create with a macro some diagrams, the diagrams gets there data from the Sheet "FG_Count". 
But i don´t know how to write the macro that it always uses the right column.

The data for the diagram is in Range B3 / D3 / F3 / H3 and the diagrams are created with a For-Loop.

Here my macro for creating the diagrams.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim v
    Dim a As Integer 

    For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If s.Visible = True Then
            v = v + 1
        End If
    Next s

    a = 1
    For i = 2 to v 
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
        With ActiveChart
            For Each s In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
                s.Delete
            Next s
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='Project Overview'!$B$" & a

            ' Here I don't know how to write the Code that it works
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='FG_Count'!$ ...."

            .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "={1}"
            .Axes(xlCategory).Select
            .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 1
        End With
        a = a + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

I could find a solution .. maybe it is not the best, but it works :)

```
For i = 2 To v
    Dep = Worksheets(i).Name

    If i = 2 Then
        ColumnLetter = "B"
    ElseIf i = 3 Then
        ColumnLetter = "D"
    ElseIf i = 4 Then
        ColumnLetter = "F"
    ElseIf i = 5 Then
        ColumnLetter = "H"
    ElseIf i = 6 Then
        ColumnLetter = "J"
    ElseIf i = 7 Then
        ColumnLetter = "L"
    ElseIf i = 8 Then
        ColumnLetter = "N"
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
    With ActiveChart
        For Each s In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
            s.Delete
        Next s
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='Project Overview'!$B$" & e
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='FG_Count'!$" & ColumnLetter & "$3"
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "={1}"
        .Axes(xlCategory).Select
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 1
    End With
Next
```

Comment: try recording a macro while doing what you need and ... get inspiration!

Answer (score 0):

The secret is knowing that the letter A has the ASCII code 65. We can then use the CHR$ function to turn an ASCII value into text. So you can replace your whole

```
 If i = 2 Then
    ColumnLetter = "B"
```

block with

```
  ColumnLetter = Chr$(64 + i)
```